# Finding the $75$th percentile of a distribution.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, percentile

So, I came across a couple of homework problems on finding percentiles. The first was:

pdf of $X$ is $f(x)=\frac{10}{x^2}$ for $x\gt 10$, and $0$ otherwise. Finding the $75$th percentile here was fine:

$$\int_{10}^{p}\frac{10}{x^2}dx=.75$$

and $p=40$.

The next problem I also had to find the $75$th percentile and I am not certain on how to go about this.

The random variable $X$ has pdf:

$$f(x) =\begin{cases}(1+x),  & {-1\lt x \le 0} \\(1-x), & {0\lt x\lt 1}  \\\end{cases}$$

A full solution isn't necessary. I'm really just hoping for help on how to set it up. I haven't been asked to find a $75$th percentile on a pdf that has more than one condition before and can't seem to make sense of it. The best I could come up with was setting both up individually and making $p$ the upper limit on each. My idea was that this could potentially show the $75$th percentile for each condition. But, I can't find anything to verify it one way or the other.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the graph of your function $f(x)$.

[image]

In particular, the pdf is symmetric about $ x = 0$, so where does the $50$th percentile lie?

The $75$th percentile of the entire function will be what percentile of the function for $x > 0$?

Comment: $\frac12$ then?

Comment: Right, you will need to find the value of $x$ which splits the area of the right triangle into half. Be careful about using pdf/integral reasoning to solve for this as you did above, since $f(x) = 1-x$ is not a probability distribution over the interval $0<x<1$. Alternatively, you can split the integral over the two domains, and proceed as your first example.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had just did an integral to do a similar problem and didn't consider that it could be as easy as looking at the graph.